# pip does not see the latest pandas version

Tags: python, pandas, pip

[pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) 1.5.3 was released on Jan 19, 2023.

However, `pip` seems to be unable to install it (same for 1.5.2 &c):

```
$ pip3 install --user pandas==1.5.3
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==1.5.3 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.23.3, 0.23.4, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 0.25.0, 0.25.1, 0.25.2, 0.25.3, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.5.3
```

also,

```
$ pip3 cache purge                                                                                                                                                       
ERROR: No matching packages
$ pip3 install --user pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.3.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3; platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64" and python_version < "3.10" in /local/home/sdsg/.virtualenvs/myself/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.21.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /local/home/sdsg/.virtualenvs/myself/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2022.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /local/home/sdsg/.virtualenvs/myself/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /local/home/sdsg/.virtualenvs/myself/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.16.0)
Installing collected packages: pandas
Successfully installed pandas-1.3.5
```

(note that `pip3 install --user sqlalchemy` installs [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) v2.0.4 so it seems to be able to see newer versions of *some* packages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Python 3.7.

However, the last available version of pandas for Python 3.7 is pandas 1.3.5.

In the pandas [release of version 1.4.0](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v1.4.0):

> See the [full whatsnew](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4.0/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html) for a list of all the changes. pandas 1.4.0 supports Python 3.8 and higher.

---

In order to use pandas 1.5.3, you will need to use a newer version of Python (Python >= 3.8 is supported).